# need help in deleting duplicate columns from a table

Tags: mysql

i have a table as follow

```
| sr_no | id | content |
|  1    |200 |   abc   |
|  2    |201 |   xyz   |
|  3    |202 |   aaa   |
|  4    |200 |   bbb   |
|  5    |300 |   ccc   |
|  6    |202 |   ddd   |
```

where `sr_no` is primary key.. now i want to remove the one of the row which have same id so the output will be

```
| sr_no | id | content |
|  1    |200 |   abc   |
|  2    |201 |   xyz   |
|  3    |202 |   aaa   |
|  5    |300 |   ccc   |
```

with all unique values in id column

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So this issue have more solutions, which dependent of different condition;)

one of them you can create new dublicate table based on distinct data of origin table, after delete original table -> after rename duplicate to original...

so but  based on this question, simple

try this:

```
  delete t1 FROM sample t1 
  INNER  JOIN sample t2 
     WHERE
       t1.sr_no < t2.sr_no AND
       t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: @ShubhamSakharkar is there a reason that you accepted this answer which does not do what you want: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rwLx63Mub7BdJQofUv2Uj3/2 and unaccepted mine?

Answer (score 0):

This subquery returns all the min `sr_no`s for each `id` and these are the rows that you want to keep:

```
select min(sr_no) sr_no 
from tablename 
group by id
```

So you can delete all the other `sr_no`s:

```
delete from tablename
where sr_no not in (
  select sr_no from (
    select min(sr_no) sr_no 
    from tablename 
    group by id
  ) t
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rwLx63Mub7BdJQofUv2Uj3/0).
Or with a self join:

```
delete t1 
from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
on t2.id = t1.id and t2.sr_no < t1.sr_no;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rwLx63Mub7BdJQofUv2Uj3/1).
Results:

```
| sr_no | id  | content |
| ----- | --- | ------- |
| 1     | 200 | abc     |
| 2     | 201 | xyz     |
| 3     | 202 | aaa     |
| 5     | 300 | ccc     |
```

Comment: this is'nt working for me as i think i have more 90000 rows.. no response from sever

Comment: Try also the 2nd query.